# Heroku database management from worker

Tags: python, heroku, redis, heroku-postgres

Wondering if anyone can help me with this or at least guide me the correct way.

I currently have a web and a worker process running. I need a task to run 24/7 while the dynos are online, it's job is to access the database and remove records that have expired by checking the "expiry" value for each record against the current timestamp.

My worker.py file:

```
import os
import redis
from rq import Worker, Queue, Connection

listen = ['high', 'default', 'low']

redis_url = os.getenv('REDISTOGO_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')

conn = redis.from_url(redis_url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Connection(conn):
        worker = Worker(map(Queue, listen))
        worker.work()
```

This is as shown by the heroku documentation.

Then in my app.py:

```
from rq import Queue
from worker import conn
from datetime import datetime

q = Queue(connection=conn)

def myFunction():
    while True:
        for item in Users.query.all():
           if int(item.expiry) < (datetime.now().timestamp()):
               db.session.delete(item)
               db.session.commit()

If __name__ == “__main__”:
    q.enqueue(myFunction)
    app.run()
```

My profile looks like so:

```
web: gunicorn app:app
worker: python worker.py
```

When I run this, expired records are not removed from the database. Is there anyway I can solve this or diagnose the issue further?

Comment: You don't seem to have anything that actually enqueues myFunction.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do have something to enqueue it but completely forgot to include that in the question! Thanks for reminding me, I’ll edit it when I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that enqueues your task is inside the `__name__ == “__main__”` block, so it only runs when your script is run directly - eg via `python app.py`. But you are running this on Heroku via the procfile, which loads it as a module into gunicorn - so that code is never executed. You need to put it somewhere else.

Note though I can't see any reason for using rq here at all. That's used for creating workers that dynamically run offline tasks when enqueued by your web processes. But you seem to want one function to run continuously; rq is irrelevant here, you should just run that code directly via the procfile.